# Deleting pointers that were allocated in another shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, delete-operator

**UPDATE (SOLVED):** All right, I'm a *complete idiot*! Turns out in the "do stuff with data" part in my main program I ended up incrementing the pointer, so the delete obviously wouldn't work! D'oh!

So I am compiling a shared library that has a function similar to this (super simplified view), and this library is also mine- so I know how data is allocated:

```
// inside library

void* getData(int size) { // with other parameters

    UINT8* data = new UINT8[size];  // where typedef uint8_t  UINT8; for gcc

    // do a socket read, where data is the buffer
    blockingRead (someSocket, data, propertySize); 

    return (void*) data;
}
```

It has to return a void pointer, as the data could be a struct (so one can just cast to the struct).

The problem is, I am using this pointer in my main program, and I want to delete it when I'm done. If I do this in my main program:

```
// inside main program
char* data = (char*) Library::getData(5);
// do stuff with data

delete[] data; // crashes with:
// *** glibc detected *** core: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00002aaab007bca4 ***
```

I thought maybe I should delete it in the shared library instead:

```
// inside library

void disposeData(void* data) {  // call this from main program
    delete[] (UINT8*) data; // cast it back to the original type of pointer
}
```

But I still get the same crash! Everything works fine and dandy if I don't delete, but I don't want unnecessary memory leaks all over my program.

I'm probably doing something dumb somewhere- please help me find the error in my ways!

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, it seems that the above code works- I will have to see what specifically causes the errors in my code.

Comment: I think you'll need to create a minimal example that exhibits your issue.  I've tried your code with g++ and it ran through just fine...no crash.

Comment: Thanks Noah! Hmm, I guess there is more to it... I'll investigate

Comment: Your problem is likely in the `// do stuff with data` part, so paste that too. You're somehow not deleting the same pointer as `Library::getData(5)` returns (perhaps because of a buffer overrun, or you're assigning something else to `data` somewhere)

Comment: Could you have already deleted data and you are trying to delete it again?

Comment: Thanks guys! Turns out nos was right, I was incrementing the pointer in the "do stuff with data" part! ARGH, sorry guys haha

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/)? Using valgrind will help you pinpoint a wide range of memory management errors, which are the likely cause of the problem. The error you are seeing looks either like heap corruption (as @nos says, probably in the do stuff part), or that you are not in fact freeing the same object you originally allocated.

Answer (score 0):

If the library is providing you with allocated pointers, it should explain how to deallocate them.  It may provide its own function for deallocation.  Unless you have the source code to the library and can verify that it is using `new[]` to create the pointer, you can't be sure how it is allocating memory.  Your crash is likely because your deallocator doesn't match its allocator.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a more RAII based design such as smart pointers instead? [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) smart pointers are quite well designed.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're doing something like that, as you mention "casts":

```
#include <stdio.h>

class B { int x; };

class C { int y; };

class A : public B, public C { };

void* getData()
{
    A* a = new A();
    printf("%p\n", a);
    C* c = a;
    printf("%p\n", c);
    return c;
}

void deleteData(void* x)
{
    // delete (A*)x; // incorrect; causes crash
    delete (A*)(C*)x; // correct
}

int main()
{
    void* x = getData();
    deleteData(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Beware, the compiler may be translating what looks like an innocent cast into pointer arithmetic behind your back.